# Hide Page Elements Cleanly On Resize

Tags: html, css, resize

I have a page with several arbitrarily-sized blocks of content. Is there a way I can:

1. Allow these blocks to resize larger or smaller to fill all available space as the window size changes,
2. Specify a minimum size for each of these blocks,
3. Hide the block completely when it will not fit on the page at the specified minimum size.

I have full control over the HTML and CSS. I would strongly prefer a solution without Javascript.

Comment: show some code mate what have you tried so far. For the first you can use 100%, for the second you can use min-width, min height and for the third you have to use javascript.

Comment: For number three, your choices are limited to [Media Queries](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries) (no IE8!) or JavaScript.

Comment: @JAA149 You should make that an answer, at least the second part.

Comment: @JAA149 By the way, I would recommend percentages in general, not just 100%.

Comment: Thanks jeroen. Yeah I guess it should be % and not 100%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@dark; may be you want a fluid website. So,

1) give `width` in percentage instead of `px` to the div for re size larger & smaller.
check more http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/09/smart-fixes-for-fluid-layouts/

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/

2) yes you can define `min-width` for your block like

```
.block{
 min-width:20%;
}
```

3) For hiding a block or change in design with certain window size you have to define min-width or max-width in `media query`. 
check the link

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

http://nathanstaines.com/demo/media-queries.html

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: The media query was exactly what I was looking for for #3.

Answer (score 2):

For the 1st, you can set `width` and `height` with a % value. This will cause the "blocks" to resize as the "window size changes". For the 2nd, you can set the `min-width` and `min-height`, so that whatever the size of the window, the blocks will not shrink smaller then your specified values. As for the 3rd, you will have to use javascript.